# Executing command non root

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I have a script which is being run as root. Part of this script calls pythons `webbrowser.open`.

Currently when `webbrowser.open` is executed it will attempt to open the browser but using the scripts `root/sudo` user.

Is there a way to open the script but as the current user and not root?

Comment: How is the script executed that causes it to run as root?

Comment: It is a terminal application which also has the option for a GUI

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should downgrade the privileges of your script, using

```
import os
os.setuid(1000)
```

Have a look to all other tools, like seteuid() and setgid() here : http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Cheers,

K.

Comment: Downgrading the permissions of the script cannot be done. As there are some options which require high level permissions

Comment: If that's the case, you can have the script call `os.fork`, and let the child process drop its privileges before exec'ing the web browser.